# Is it possible to create a Mongo view using spring-data-mongo 1.10?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a simple requirement to be able to create a Mongo view from my Java app.  We're using the 3.4 Mongo driver and spring-data-mongo 1.10.2.  [The Mongo docs for `db.createCollection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/db.createCollection/) indicate you create a view by including `viewOn` in the options, but the `CollectionOptions` class that is used by `mongoTemplate.createCollection` doesn't have this property.

I've dug through source code up to s-d-m version 2.2 and still don't see it supported. How can I create a view?

Comment: I'm also looking to create Mongo view in spring-data-mongo. Have you found any solutions yet. Could you share your solution here if you've found one?

Comment: @Sujal I posted my solution, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this working.  Below is the method:

```
private void createView(BaseEntity model, String viewName, String viewDefinition) {
    // Get the model's @Document annotation so we can determine its collection
    Document doc = model.getClass().getAnnotation(Document.class);
    Assert.notNull(doc, "Error - @Document annotation is null for model class: " + model.getClass().getSimpleName());

    // Attempt to create the view
    CommandResult result = mongoTemplate.executeCommand("{" +
        "create: '" + viewName + "', " +
        "viewOn: '" + doc.collection() + "', " +
        "pipeline: [{$match: " + viewDefinition + "}]" +
    "}");

    if(result.ok()) {
        LOGGER.info("Successfully created view '{}' on collection '{}'", viewName, doc.collection());
    }
    else {
        throw new ViewCreationBeanException(
            "Failed to create view '" + viewName + "' on collection '" + doc.collection() + "' - " + result.getErrorMessage(),
            result.getException()
        );
    }
}
```

`model` is the Java class with the `@Document` annotation that specifies the mongo collection.  What I was doing here was creating a view on a model based on its underlying collection.  `viewDefinition` are the view constraints, a `String` such as: `"{deleted: {$ne: true}}"`.